# Setting cell data validation as list from a variable list

Tags: vba, excel

Am quite new to VBA and am piecing together my developments one step at at time searching for answers online but have hit a snag.

I'm struggling to understand how the creation of the data validation list code works. The beginning "With WrkBook.Range("H3").Validation" is where I'm putting the drop down list? Seems 'yes' from one posting, but another seemed to have the "With" followed by the actual range which contains the list. Secondly, the "Formula1:=..." I believe is also the location of the list. However, I seem to be only able to include the first cell in my list as being included in the list. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
Dim WrkBook As Worksheet
Dim LastCellRowNumber As Integer
Dim ListRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range

Set WrkBook = Worksheets("Misc Ref")

'Find
WrkBook.Activate
Range("A100000").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select

LastCellRowNumber = ActiveCell.Row

ActiveSheet.Cells(LastCellRowNumber, 1).Select

    Set ListRng = WrkBook.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastCellRowNumber, 1))

    With WrkBook.Range("H3").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=WrkBook.ListRng
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
 Set ListRng = WrkBook.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastCellRowNumber, 1))
```

you already set or assign a Range Object referenced at `WrkBook` sheet object.
So you don't have to use `WrkBook.ListRng` in assigning the *Formula1* argument.
Also, *Formula1* argument is suppose to be the address of the source range in the form of string.

So it should be something like:

```
Formula1:= "=" & ListRng.Address
```

This will fail though if the worksheet your putting the validation list is not the same worksheet of the source list. So you might want to add:

```
Formula1:= "=" & ListRng.Address(, , xlA1, True)
```

That will give you the Sheet name  as well. HTH.

**Edit2:** Based on comments and no need to use *Split function*.

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range, lrow As Long
    With Sheets("Misc Ref")
        lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set r = .Range("A2:A" & lrow)
    End With
    'Debug.Print "=" & r.Address(, , xlA1, True)
    With Sheets("Summary").Range("H10").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & r.Address(, , xlA1, True)
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Setting the *Address property **External** argument* to `True` includes the full path.
But if you assign it to a validation formula, it automatically disregards the Workbook name.
So there is no need to use ***Split Function***. No need to worry the apostrophe then. HTH.

Comment: Actually it is the same worksheet, for now, as I'm trying to keep it simple to make it work. But it will be a different worksheet I'm putting the data validation so thanks. But in either case I get this: 

http://i.imgur.com/Op07yV8.png

Comment: Ok, removed the "." and now get this (and it's highlighting the formula line and line above when I debug):

http://i.imgur.com/rWpvpmW.png

Comment: @james9487 `Range("A1")` should be `ListRng`. My bad. I was also testing it at my end and was using a normal Range address, not an assign variable.

Comment: Same error: http://i.imgur.com/N2XnH6K.png
And could you explain where exactly I'm specifying where the data validation list will be inserted (I'll want it in a single cell in my 'Summary' worksheet)?

Comment: @james9487 Nah, you're putting it in WrkBook sheet which is worksheet "Misc Ref". It should work, tried and tested in my end. Anyways, I'll try to re-write your whole code for you.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate it. And if it helps, I simply want this range (http://i.imgur.com/RGv0Bxg.png) on worksheet 'Misc Ref' to be the data validation list on worksheet 'Summary' cell "H10". And of course this list of weeks will change in length.

Comment: `Ok, but what am i doing wrong then?` We are missing `'` since you are referencing on a Sheet with space on the its name. So it should be `='Misc Ref'!$A$2:$A$lrow`. What we're currently generating is `=Misc Ref'!$A$2:$A$lrow` (we are lacking the opening apostrophe)

Comment: Still didn't work. So I just started a new workbook with the proper tabs and data and it now works. I appreciate your help. Any idea why it wouldn't work when I tried replacing my existing code with what you had above? Seems like VBA might have some quirks much like it's beast of a sibling Excel does?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. VBA is a picky little thing. Look forward to developing my understanding. Thanks again. Can't upvote your reply as I don't have 10 reputation.

Comment: @james9487 See my edit. We are overdoing things. Excel automatically adjust the ***Address*** of the range when you assign it as *Validation Formula*. So no need to worry about the apostrophe.